# How to connect rabbitMQ using JWT token

Tags: oauth-2.0, rabbitmq

The problem is resumed in the title. I need to connect to rabbit MQ using oauth2.

Any advice ? i saw this plugin: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2 but i can't build it, and there is no binaries.

Comment: This plugin is still experimental. Which version of RabbitMQ do you use? Not that it must be compiled against the unreleased version [3.8 of RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2#supported-rabbitmq-versions).

Comment: I use the 3.7...

Comment: This plugin *must* be compiled against the unreleased version 3.8 of RabbitMQ. it will *not* work with RabbitMQ 3.7. You will have to wait until 3.8 is released.